Missing Object Reference Library in vba "IBM Access Client Solutions Library"
I want to connect in IACS application, and do some command.
However, when checking the reference library, I only have "IBM I Access for Windows ActiveX Object Library".
I do search that PCOMM library are able to connect in IACS?
